# A query is returning an ActiveRecord::Relation, not the actual data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, I am pretty new to programming, but have fell in love with rails over other applicaitons,   but I've tried navigating Railscasts, rubyonrails.org, and several other places, but I'm truly lost.

In a controller, "weekly_review_controller.rb", I have:

```
def show
  @weeklyReviewData = []
  currentBusinessEmployees = current_user.thisUsersBusiness.employees.uniq
  @weekStart = "Sun, 2 Dec 2012 00:00 -0500".to_datetime
  @weekEnd = @weekStart+7.days-1.second
  currentBusinessEmployees.each do |t|
    # Vars
    @employeeWeeklyData = []
    # Names
    @employeeWeeklyData << t.firstName + " " + t.lastName
    # DailyData
    dStop = t.dailyData.select("deliveryStop").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
    dPkg = t.dailyData.select("deliveryPackage").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
    pStop = t.dailyData.select("pickupStop").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
    pPkg = t.dailyData.select("pickupPackage").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
    iLS = t.dailyData.select("inboundLocalService").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
    @employeeWeeklyData << dStop << dPkg << pStop << pPkg << iLS
    @weeklyReviewData << @employeeWeeklyData
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.haml
    format.json { render json: @weeklyReviewData }
  end
end
```

So I haven't figured out to pass in the url as a `param` yet (hence the static definitions of the start and end dates, even though I do have the URL being passed the UTC timecode "`/weekly_review/2012-12-02%2013:00:00%20UTC`"), but that will come, when I learn a little more.   What I am focusing on, since I have a very beautiful view, (ask and I will post), I want to populate the table I made in the view, with the data that I have collected.   The problem is that the variable that is passed to the view, `@weeklyReviewData` is populating the employee names (`t.firstName + " " + t.lastName`) fine, but the rest of the data is all `Active:Relation:`jumble.  I have watched/read, and am pretty sure that the purpose of this is store, in a cache, some of the data form the database by `lazy lookups` (or so what people seem to refer it to), but that also is for another day.  I just want the data from the database just like the names.

So what is wrong with my queries below?:

```
  dStop = t.dailyData.select("deliveryStop").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
  dPkg = t.dailyData.select("deliveryPackage").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
  pStop = t.dailyData.select("pickupStop").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
  pPkg = t.dailyData.select("pickupPackage").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
  iLS = t.dailyData.select("inboundLocalService").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd )
```

Trials/notes:

I have even used the queries in the rails console and done `puts t.dailyData.select("deliveryStop").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", "Sun, 2 Dec 2012 00:00 -0500".to_datetime, "Sat, 9 Dec 2012 11:59 -0500".to_datetime ).to_sql`, and the SQL query seems pretty legit, but obviously I am missing something.

The SQL puts is: `SELECT deliveryStop FROM "daily_data" INNER JOIN "daily_data_employees" ON "daily_data"."id" = "daily_data_employees"."dailyDatum_id" WHERE "daily_data_employees"."employee_id" = 2 AND (startTime > '2012-12-02 05:00:00' AND endTime < '2012-12-09 16:59:00')`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could come up with a smaller code example that demonstrates the problem. Your question contains a lot of extraneous information that makes it harder to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood, all the data you want/need is present in the `ActiveRecord::Relation`. An `ActiveRecord::Relation` can be (mostly) treated as an array, so you can iterate ove r it to fetch the data. If you prefer, you can explicitly convert it into an array using the `to_a` method. If you expect only one match, Tudo Constantin's answer is useful.

Comment: In the `rails c`, checking by adding `.first`, I still get this as a return: `#<DailyDatum deliveryStop: 20>`, but not `20`.   Why is this?

Comment: That is because the query is returning instances of the `DailyDatum` class, with only the fields that you selected in your query set. After the call to `.first`, you still have a single `DailyDatum` instance left, but if you want to know the `deliveryStop`, you have to call the `deliveryStop` method on that instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try by explicitly telling `ActiveRecord` to fetch one record:

```
dStop = t.dailyData.select("deliveryStop").where( "startTime > ? AND endTime < ?", @weekStart, @weekEnd ).first
```